# Simple push in SWRevealViewController for single cell swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am working with SWRevealViewController. used this code

```
 @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    if self.revealViewController() != nil {

        menuButton.target = self //.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = Selector("backAction")
        menuButton.image = UIImage(named: "back_arrow")
        menuButton.title = ""

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

    }




func backAction()
{
   self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

But now i want 1 view controller with out this functionality. i.e. i don't want menu button for "Login" need just simple push with back button.

Now i can't go back to Navigation Drawer or Main screen.

Any help will much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What is the problem, crash?

Comment: @Bearwithme. could you check now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key menuButton.' --> the error says

in your `menuButton` is not connected properly in your storyboard, remove the connection once and again ,it will work

Comment: Updated my question now. could you check now?

Comment: check once your previous viewcontroller is availbe or not in navigation stack , the reason SWL is works with in custom segue not a navigation segue

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `menuButton` outlet is **correctly** connected in Interface Builder.

Comment: Updated my question now. could you check now?